# How to add "New Stylesheet" to the New File Menu?

Tags: stylesheet, menu

What's the easiest way of adding an option for opening a "New Stylesheet" to the File > New submenu.

[image]

Comment: Do you *really* want to create a new stylesheet from scratch by means of such a File > New menu entry? Ordinarily, I think, folks create a new stylesheet by opening `Default.nb` (or perhaps, at a lower-level, `Core.nb`) from `$InstallationDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets`, modifying it, and saving it in `$UserAddOnsDirectory/SystemFiles/FrontEnd/StyleSheets`.

Comment: I do, I like to create new ones frequently and it would be very convenient!